# PHP Laravel - Composed Key - Error relathionship *RECURSION*

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i trying to make a relathionship with a composed key table, but laravel returning a recusrsion bug. How to solve this?

Database tables:

```
create table permission
(
    permission_id int auto_increment
        primary key
);

create table role
(
    role_id int auto_increment
        primary key
);

create table role_permission
(
    role_id       int not null,
    permission_id int not null,
    primary key (role_id, permission_id)
);
```

Laravel Role Model with relathionship

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'role';

    public function permissions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Permission::class, 'role_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Generated Error/Bug:
https://pastebin.com/YfBWTBxR

Comment: Try to set `$primaryKey` in both models since framework expects [default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) to be `id`.

Comment: @Tpojka i tryied this, but the error persists, i tryied also, get only data of table role_permission, but give error too

Comment: Are you still liberated to change those name to follow [framework's naming convention and best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)? If so, it should be easy as `return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class)`. If not, [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L463-L506) you have definition of method - you need to put more arguments there.

Answer (score 1):

Your database schema shows that roles and permissions are in a many to many relation, so you should use the `belongsToMany` method instead of `hasMany`. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many for details

Comment: i changed the code using many-to-many $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class)->using(RolePermission::class); but dont work

Comment: you need to define it on both classes

Comment: sorry, i not undestand this, all related classes Permission, RolePermission, must be have belogns?

Comment: You only need 2 classes: Role and Permission, a Role should belong to many permission, and also a Permission should belong to many roles.

Comment: yes, but the table RolePermission is dinamyc and make relathionship with Roles and Permissions